# Type is not generic enough error when wrapping a function with parameters with lifetimes

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime, higher-order-functions

I have a generic higher-order function in an external library that takes in a `FnMut`, wraps it, and returns similar to this:

```rust
fn foo<T>(mut f:impl FnMut(T) -> T) -> impl FnMut(T)-> T{
    move |t|f(t)
}
```

I decided to write a wrapper to handle a specific case:

```
fn bar(f:impl FnMut(&str) -> &str) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> &str{
    foo(f)
}
```

However, the compiler errored out saying that one of the types wasn't general enough:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:39
  |
1 | fn foo<T>(mut f:impl FnMut(T) -> T) -> impl FnMut(T)-> T{
  |                                        -----------------
  |                                        |
  |                                        the expected opaque type
  |                                        the found opaque type
...
4 | fn bar(f:impl FnMut(&str) -> &str) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> &str{
  |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
  |
  = note: expected associated type `<impl FnMut<(&str,)> as FnOnce<(&str,)>>::Output`
             found associated type `<impl FnMut<(&str,)> as FnOnce<(&str,)>>::Output`
```

It compiles perfectly fine if I use a type without lifetimes like `i32`, and writing out the HRTBs doesn't change the error. Best I can tell, the compiler is having trouble matching the lifetimes of the function outputs, but I can't figure out why it's having trouble and how to work around it.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5d55ac43ada5a92cf8766a4d18ab1f0f)

Comment: I believe to fix this, instead of `T`, you'd need to use some sort of type constructor with HRTBs, something like `fn foo< T<'a> >(f: impl for<'a> FnMut(T<'a>) -> T<'a>) -> impl for<'a> FnMut(T<'a>) -> T<'a>`, although this syntax doesn't exist in rust yet and not sure if it could be implemented using GATs currently.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues Yeah you're probably right being able to bound the lifetime of `T` somehow would fix the issue, but I don't think that's possible currently, and `foo` comes from an external library so I can't modify it anyway. What I am hoping is that somebody knows how to bound `bar` or modify the signature in a way that would allow something reasonably close to this to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the original `foo` signature requires that both functions take the exact same argument, so the only way to fix it would be to have a lifetime `'a` in `bar` and use `&'a str` so that input and output types are equal, [as such](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9b288df94a5f0aea61f4ac69ccbdd5fe).

Comment: This, however, is more restrictive, and so may not be appropriate for your use case

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues that works for my use case, the compiler can infer the lifetime appropriately. If you make that into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, rust doesn't currently allow you to create a general enough `foo` for your `bar` example.

But if you modify `bar` so that the caller chooses the lifetime of `f`, instead of it being generic over all lifetimes, you can make it work with the current `foo`:

```rust
fn foo<T>(mut f: impl FnMut(T) -> T) -> impl FnMut(T)-> T {
    move |t| f(t)
}

fn bar<'a>(f: impl FnMut(&'a str) -> &'a str) -> impl FnMut(&'a str) -> &'a str {
    foo(f)
}
```

This is technically more restrictive, but for most use cases, it should be equivalent.